# Insert links into image row directly beside it (E.g B2 Photo wants A2 link]

Tags: vba, excel

I’ve looked up a lot of solutions online but I can’t seem to find anything that does what I require

Cell A1, A2 and onwards contains the links to the pictures
Cells B1, B2 and so forth contains the pictures that my VBA grabs from a folder.
I want each photo image in B to contain the link so that when you click the image it goes to photo URL.
I have:

```
Sub Adwadwawda()

Dim mylink As String
Dim pic As Shape
Dim lnk As Hyperlink

mylink = "www.pageurl.com"

Set pic = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Picture 1")

Set lnk = Worksheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=pic, Address:=mylink)

End Sub
```

I am trying to modify this to get each cell to the left E.g B3 Photo wants A3 link.  The range (number of rows in each column A and B) changes daily as photos are added.

VBA to add images from a Folder..

```
Sub AddOlEObject()

    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Folderpath = "C:\Users\Pictures\Saved Pictures"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                 counter = counter + 1
                  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).Value = fls.Name
                  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & counter).ColumnWidth = 25
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & counter).RowHeight = 100
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & counter).Activate
                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter)
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
            End If

        End If
    Next
mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter)
'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 70
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True

    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to loop through all shapes an use the TopLeftCell Property together with offset to read the link-address from the cell left to the cell in which the Top-Left corner resides:

```
Sub Adwadwawda()
Dim Shp As Shape, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each Shp In ws.Shapes
        If Shp.TopLeftCell.Column = 2 Then _
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Shp, Shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm I seem to get Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error. and it highlights yellow ws.hyperlinks.  Not sure why

Comment: Do you have shapes other than the pictures in column B? I edit the sub to check this...

Comment: I have attached the vba I am using to my post.  I then manually type in links in column A.  Lastly, I use the vba you provided.  It says address not valid.

Comment: Apologies.  I was putting in www.google.com instead of http://www.google.com.au.  Haha!  Thanks it works perfectly!